# Given an ID, return data that DOESN'T have the same category as the given ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: video, video_category and video_category_join.

One video can have multiple video_category and a video_category can be associated with multiple videos: therefore the video_category_join table

**TABLE: video**

```
| video_id | title | description | duration |
|--------------------------------------------
| 12       | hello | ...         | 190      |
| 24       | hello | ...         | 190      |
| 78       | hello | ...         | 190      |
| 34       | hello | ...         | 190      |
| 91       | hello | ...         | 190      |
| 88       | hello | ...         | 190      |
```

**TABLE: video_category**

```
| video_category_id | name    |
|------------------------------
| 4                 | music   |
| 8                 | tv      |
| 5                 | black   |
| 2                 | politic |
| 1                 | movie   |
| 6                 | other   |
```

**TABLE: video_category_join**

```
| video_id | video_category_id |
|------------------------------
| 24       | 4                 |
| 24       | 5                 |
| 88       | 1                 |
| 91       | 6                 |
| 91       | 5                 |
| 78       | 4                 |
```

Given a `video_id`, i want to pick random videos that DON'T have the same category as the given `video_id`.

So, for example, if the `video_id` is 24, the result set should return videos that dont have the same category as `video_id` 24. In this case, the only videos that dont have the same category as `video_id` 24 are: `video_id` 88.

This is a query that i thought could work, but if the given `video_id` has no categories it returns nothing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.video_id, v.title, v.duration, 2 AS preferred
FROM video_category_join vc
JOIN video_category_join vc2 ON vc2.video_category_id <> vc.video_category_id AND vc2.video_id <> vc.video_id
JOIN video v ON v.video_id = vc2.video_id
WHERE vc.video_id = 5
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses a self-join and aggregation.  The join matches on the categories; the `having` returns videos that do not share any categories:

```
select vc.video_id
from video_category vc left join
     video_category vc2
     on vc2.video_category_id = vc.video_category_id and
        vc2.video_id = 5
group by vc.video_id
having count(vc2.video_id) = 0;
```

Comment: This is not random, also it does not work because there is no such column named category in table video_category.

Comment: when the columns named are corrected, it works perfectly.

Comment: if it helps, i've tried using `WHERE vc2.video_id IS NULL` instead of `HAVING COUNT ...` and for some reason, `HAVING COUNT` is a really bit faster

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with joins

```sql
select * from video where video_id not in (
  select distinct v.video_id from video v
  left join video_category_join vc
  on v.video_id = vc.video_id
  where vc.video_category_id in (
    select video_category_id
    from video_category_join
    where video_id = 24)
 )
 order by rand()
 limit 5
```

This will select 5 random videos that are not in the same category as video #24

Comment: this solution doesn't quite work. It returns video_id 91, even though it's not supposed to.

Comment: @Marco yeah, you are right. I fixed it now. It is quite long tho :D any ideas making it shorter?